# Have hover effects active only for screens 1200px and up

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make it so that, when the screen is 1200px or greater in width, then I want to have some hover effects in place. If the screen sizes is less than 1200px, then the hover effects are NOT supposed to happen.

In screens 1200px and up, when hovering over the fun-stuff-slide element, the 2 buttons are supposed to show. When hovering out, they are hidden by changing the opacity.

In screens under 1200px, the buttons are supposed to show all the time.

So far, I can't get my jQuery or CSS to work consistently. I know that the resizing works as I put in a test console log message and screen size is recorded whenever the screen is resized. Also, everything works on page load but when you start hovering, then things break.

Here is the jQuery:

```
        var $window = $(window);
        function checkWidth() {
            var windowsize = $window.width();


            if (windowsize > 1200) {
                console.log("larger screens");
                $('.fun-stuff-slider').hover(function () {
                    $learnButton = $(this).find('.button--learn-more');
                    $downloadButton = $(this).find('.download-now-link');
                    $downloadButton.css({ 'opacity': '1' });
                    $learnButton.css({ 'opacity': '1' });
                }, function () {

                    $downloadButton.css({ 'opacity': '0' });
                    $learnButton.css({ 'opacity': '0' });
                });
            }

            else {
                $learnButton = $(this).find('.button--learn-more');
                $downloadButton = $(this).find('.download-now-link')
                $learnButton.css({ 'opacity': '1' });
                $downloadButton.css({ 'opacity': '1' });
            }
        }

        // Execute on load
        checkWidth();
        // Bind event listener
        $(window).resize(checkWidth);
```

CSS:

```
.cta {
        position: relative !important;
        height: auto;
        color: white;
        width: auto;
        font-size: 1rem;
        font-weight: bold;
        margin-top: 6rem;
        opacity: 1;
        @include breakpoint(xlarge) {
            opacity: 0;
        }
    }

 a.button--learn-more {
    font-size: 1rem !important;
    order: 2;
    padding: 0.85em 0.33em;
    transform: translateY(-6rem);
    margin-bottom: 0;
    width: 152px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    z-index: 9;
    opacity: 1;
    @include breakpoint(xlarge) {
        opacity: 0;
  }
```

HTML:

```
            <div class="extra-content coloring-container">
                @For Each coloringItem As Tuple(Of tblPage, KeyValuePair(Of tblFile, List(Of tblFile))) In ViewData("PublicShell")("Files")

                    @<div Class="item slick-slide slick-active fun-stuff-slider" data-slick-index="2" aria-hidden="false" tabindex="-1" role="option" aria-describedby="slick-slide02" style="width: 233px;">
                        <a class="button small button--learn-more" href="@(coloringItem.Item1.tblPageName.PageName)">Learn More <i class="fa fa-fw fa-arrow-circle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                        <a href="@(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("UploadDirectory"))@(coloringItem.Item2.Key.File)" target="_blank" tabindex="0" class="shared-dow">

                            @If coloringItem.Item2.Value.Count > 0 Then
                                @<img src="@(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("UploadDirectory"))@(coloringItem.Item2.Value.First.File)" alt="@(coloringItem.Item2.Value.First.AltText)" class="coloring-thumbnail" />
                            End If

                            <div class="cta download-now-link">Download Now <i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                Next
            </div>
```

Comment: CSS Media, no javascript needed

Comment: Any reason why you're not also using media queries in your css?  It might simplify things a bit.  For example:  @media screen and (min-width:1200) {}

Comment: Any reason why you don't do this with pure CSS? Should be simple since the elements you're toggling are children of the hovered `div`.

Comment: @epascarello
OMFG That's 100% correct, and it was staring right at me. I've been working on this project a lot lately and I think I am getting burned out. Sorry, Guys. Thanks, though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @epascarello already mentioned, you do not need any JS for this. Here's an example of a hover effect that will only trigger at 1200px and up using mediaqueries. (open the snippet as full page to see the hover effect):

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  a:hover {
    background: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Hover me</a>
```

For further information check out [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
var windowWidth = window.screen.width;
```

Comment: replace it with var windowsize = $window.width();

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't fix it completely. Right now, everything works for 1200px and up but not at all for under 1200px. The else statement isn't even being targeted for some reason.

Comment: @skimc990 see my answer

Answer (score 0):

Remove the hover event if the window is smaller then 1200

```
else {
    ...//
    $('.fun-stuff-slider').off('hover');
  ..//
```

I suggest you use a class and toggle that class depending on the screen size

Comment: It works on page load for 1200px and up and below, except the hover is not getting removed in the else statement. I have no idea why.

Comment: is the else statement triggering?

Comment: @skimc990 do you have a `window.resize` event?

Comment: I was able to just skip all the jQuery and use CSS, which was much easier